# Not able to append command line variable in shell script

Tags: shell

Here is my code:

```
export ALLOW_RPM_UPGRADE=True
path='/opt/rpm/latest/'
echo $1
file=$1
echo $file
dest=${path}${file}
echo $dest
cp $source $dest
```

Problem:

- The three echo statements are printing the same value.
- The third one is not appending path to `$dest` variable.

Comment: What is the argument that you are passing ?

Comment: @Anmol Singh Jaggi: Parameter is filepath. "filename.rpm"

Comment: @AmarPatil Okay. It is working on my system. Can you show us the output you're getting ?

Comment: [root@Proxy ~]# ./rpm_deployment.sh "client-4.2-6086.x86_64.rpm"
/opt/rpm/latest/
client-4.2-6086.x86_64.rpm
client-4.2-6086.x86_64.rpm
client-4.2-6086.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Please add the information to the question so it can be formatted properly (and please format it properly when you add it).  Then delete the comment.

Comment: You should be using more double quotes.  The first `export` line is not needed in an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You don't show how `source` is set, but that line isn't really needed in an MCVE either.  Taking the core of the example, extracting it into a script, and then running it with an argument `filename` produces '`filename`' twice and '`/opt/rpm/latest/filename`' once.  In the absence of information to the contrary, the code in your question works, but if you've got a problem in your real script, your real script is significantly different from the example.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ For example, if your assignment to `dest` with `path` occurs within a loop that's fed from a pipe but the final `echo` is after the loop, then it is all explicable — in such cases, the loop is in a subshell, so it can't set the variables in the main shell script.  Have you run your script fragment with `bash -x script.sh filename`?  What does it produce?  If it produces `/opt/rpm/latest/filename` then you know that the fragment isn't the same as the real script.  If produces something else, show the output (it won't be all that long).

Comment: Problem here is after every echo statements I am getting all strings with appended by "\r" Hence third statement is printing only file name.  Help me to avoid /r in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I had created shell script on windows machine. Before executing it on linux we need to covert it through DOS2Unix utility. OR Just create shell script on Linux and save.

After this it is working fine.

Thanks